# Prove that $x$ is bounded.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives, dynamical-systems, lipschitz-functions

Suppose that $x: \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+$ and that

$$
\frac{d x}{d t}  \leq x^2 $$
$$\int_0^{\infty} x(s) d s  <\infty $$

Post edit:( from the valuable comments)

Prove that  $x$ is bounded. (Note: this is not obvious since the integral constraint does not eliminate singularities like $1 / \sqrt{t}$.

As a hint I am thinking $x^2$ as $x(t) x(t)$ and thinking about how to solve $x^{\prime}=a(t) x(t)$ but didn't get any help so far.

Comment: What is $\frac {dx} {dt}$ is $x$ is not real valued?

Comment: @geetha290krm: it's written that $x(t)>0$, so in particular it is real-valued.

Comment: @Ri-Li: You write "all $t$", but is it $t>0$ or $t\in \mathbb R$ or what? Also, are you sure about the conclusion? Shouldn't it be $x(t)\le C$ for some (finite) constant $C>0$?

Comment: The question is ill-posed. If $x$ is a function $x :[0,\infty ) \to \mathbb R$ then $x(t)$ cannot take the value $\infty$ - there is no real number named $\infty$

Comment: Maybe the question is ill-posed but that is what I got. Your comment makes sense as being a continuous solution it can't reach infinity. In ODE we always try for $t \in (-\infty, \infty). @GiuseppeNegro yes it should be $x(t) \leq C$ for all $t$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $x:\mathbb{R^+}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^+}$ is of class $C^1$. Since $x\left(t\right)>0$ we have
$$
\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}\leq{x(t)}
$$
for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Then
$$
\int_{0}^{s}\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}dt \leq
\int_{0}^{s}{x(t)}dt \leq
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x(t)}dt = c <\infty
$$
for all $s>0$. Since the integral on the left side equals $\ln{x\left(s\right)}$ we have $x\left(s\right)\leq{e^c}$ so that $x$ is bounded.

Answer (score 3):

**This is answer to the original formulation of the question, where $x:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^+$.**

In fact $x$ does not need to be bounded if indeed defined for all $t\in \mathbb R$. To see it, consider the function
$$
  x(t) = \begin{cases}
t^2, & \text{ if } t\leq 0 \\
0,& \text{ if } t \geq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Its derivative is negative on $(-\infty,0)$ and zero on $[0,\infty)$, so the inequality $x'\leq x^2$ is satisfied  trivially. Likewise the integral condition is satisfied trivially as $\int_0^\infty x(s)ds = 0$.

Comment: I think you are right the time is $[0,\infty)$. Edited